# HTML5 MVC 3 left navigation layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I am creating a new web application using ASP.NET MVC3 Razor and HTML 5.

I know not all browsers support HTML5 yet but still I would like to try it out.

has anybody made any page with a left navigation layout? I would like an interface similar to Gmail ( or outlook ) with a navigation bar full height on the left side and the page content taking all available space on the right.

any guide lines on how to make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All it takes is a couple of css constructs to achieve the result you want:

```
#left { float:left; width: 200px; }
#rest { margin-left: 200px; }
```

Then your html is something like:

```
<div id="left">...</div><div id="rest">...</div>
```

And, as far as I know, it does not depend on HTML5 at all (considering the loose definition of HTML5 were CSS3 is usually included...).

Answer (score 0):

As Miguel said it's just a matter of CSS, to accomplish the full height, you need to add a couple of css properties. This will be your css file style.css:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.rest {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

And the following will be your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left">your menu here</div>
        <div class="rest">your content here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find a plunkr at this url [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sQmYKGEou8HjPDJVVtgi?p=preview)